# RxSwift Use withLatestFrom operator with multiple sources

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, reactive, combine

I have 3 observables, namely `source`, `source1` and `source2`. What I want is whenever `source` emits a distinct event to get the value of `source1` and `source2`. This is the code I've come up with, obviously it won't compile since `withLatestFrom` expects only one observable.

```
source.distinctUntilChanged()
    .withLatestFrom(source1, source2) { ($0, $1.0, $1.1) }
    .subscribe(onNext: { (A, B, C) in
        print("OnNext called")
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You almost have it. How about just combining `source1` and `source2`?

```
source.distinctUntilChanged()
    .withLatestFrom(Observable.combineLatest(source1, source2)) { ($0, $1.0, $1.1) }
    .subscribe(onNext: { (A, B, C) in
        print("OnNext called")
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
valuesSource
        .withUnretained(self) { ($0, $1.0, $1.1, $1.2, $1.3) }
        .withLatestFrom(transactionSource) { ($0, $1) }
        .withLatestFrom(userSource) { ($0.0, $0.1, $1) }
        .map { values, transaction, user -> [SectionType] in
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
        let source = PublishSubject<Int>()
        let source1 = PublishSubject<Int>()
        let source2 = PublishSubject<Int>()

        Observable
            .combineLatest([source,source1,source2])
            .distinctUntilChanged { (oldArray, newArray) -> Bool in
                return oldArray.first == newArray.first
            }
            .subscribe(onNext: { (values) in
                debugPrint("source1 value is \(values[1]) and source2 value is \(values[2])")
            })
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

        source1.onNext(100)
        source2.onNext(200)
        source.onNext(3)

        source.onNext(4)
        source.onNext(4)
```

**O/P will look like**
[image]

**Catch:**

I am using `combineLatest` that means this will work only after all the observables emitted values at least once. You can always use `startWith` operator to ensure all your observables emits value at least once.